# Has a US President's family member ever been indicted or arrested during or after the Presidential term?

Tags: united-states, law, president, family

No United States president has ever been indicted or charged with a crime during or after their presidency. (According to my search / [this Quora post](https://www.quora.com/Has-any-American-president-ever-been-indicted))

Has a president's family member ever been indicted or charged during or after their presidency?

I know their family gets secret service protection, often (always?) after the president has left office. But I could not find any *formal* legal protections on them.  Has it ever happened, or has the informal legal protection prevented it throughout US history?

Defining family member: Part of their nuclear family at the time of the indictment. The president could be dead when it happens, and would still be interested.

Edge cases that don't strictly fulfill the question (e.g arrest but not indictment, or non-nuclear but still close family member) are still interesting/noteworthy, but probably worth starting with this more narrow criteria.

Comment: [Roger Clinton](https://www.washingtonpost.com/news/the-fix/wp/2016/06/06/millennials-meet-roger-clinton-hillarys-brother-in-law-who-just-got-arrested-once-again/) Arrested for DUI.  (not clear if there was an indictment; not sure if OP is using it in the sense that would require a [grand jury](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grand_jury), or in the sense where it means "accuse".)  If the latter sense, the question would seem to be quite restrictive.

Comment: @MCW:  There was no indictment for DUI.

Comment: Several of Abraham Lincoln's brothers-in-law were rebel soldiers and thus could have been charged with treason. Former Prsident John Tyler (1790-1862 served in the Confederate Cngress and could have been charged with treason, and some of his sons were Rebel officials and soldiers. and could have been charged with treason.

Comment: @MCW/@njuffa: Updated question with link for my assumption, and also defining family member for purpose of the question

Comment: Not an indictment, but the heat on Billy Carter definitely did effect politics. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Billy_Carter#Relationship_with_Libya

Comment: No one who took part in the Confederate military or government could have been charged with treason because President Andrew Johnson issued a blanket pardon to EVERYONE involved including Confederate President Jeff Davis and VP Alex Stephens.

Comment: Was Ted Kennedy ever charged over Mary Jo Kopechne's death?

Comment: This question could stand to be updated.